# Writing a Class that Reads a Dictionary with at least one Entry

Tags: python, class

So what I am trying to do is write a class called Website, the constructor of the class will accept a dictionary representing this and will store this in a variable called links. However if the dictionary passed as a parameter isn't valid with at least one entry then a ValueError should be raised, returning something along the lines of 'At least one page must exist'

With the code I have written I am not too sure how close I am unfortunately.

```
class website:
    def __init__(self,dictionary):
        self.links = dictionary
        try:
            len(self.links)==0
        except:
            raise ValueError('The website must contain at least one page.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `if`:

```
class Website:
    def __init__(self, links):
        if not links:
            raise ValueError('The website must contain at least one page.')
        self.links = links
```

Btw, name your variables after it's contents and not it's type. Testing the validity of parameters should be the first thing in a method.

If you need a dictionary, then the best way to do so, is to test implicitly, whether the parameter is convertible into a dictionary or not:

```
class Website:
    def __init__(self, links):
        links = dict(links)
        if not links:
            raise ValueError('The website must contain at least one page.')
        self.links = links
```

You get a TypeError if you call this function with `2`, but that's totally correct, the cause is a wrong type and not a invalid Value.

This has also the side effect, that you get a copy of the dictionary, so you cannot modify it by accident in the caller's code afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I should've added that I am wanting it to pass a test such as website(2). Thanks for the tip on variable names, I will make sure to apply it.

Comment: @MrWallace: Why should anybody create this class with `2` as the parameter? Please be more specific what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `try` - `except` block for this as `len(self.links)==0` does not raise any exception. You can use the `if` statement instead,

```
if not self.links:
    raise ValueError('The website must contain at least one page.')
```

Comment: The problem I run into with this is that if there is different object types such as an int it will not run.

Comment: `len(self.links)==0` will raise if `self.links` is not a `Sequence` or other `Sized` type. So his current code does reject someone calling `website(2)`, while your code will not. Although I'm not sure what the point of that is (especially since it sounds like he wants `website(2)` to *pass*?!), it's conceivable there might be a point. So he may need both checks: it is a sequence (which he sort of got, by accident), and also it's not empty (which he got wrong).

Answer (score 0):

According to what you asked afterwards in the comments, here is my answer :

```
class Website:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.links = dictionary
        try:
            if len(self.links) > 0:
                print "Valid entry"
            else:
                raise ValueError('The website must contain at least one page.')
        except TypeError:
            raise ValueError('The link is invalid (Bad dictionnary).')
```

I took the liberty of putting a capital W on Website, this is a convention I like to follow for classes, also I caught a specific TypeError Exception and not a generic one.
If you created a Website(2), it raises first a TypeError within your __init__() then a ValueError. The rest is pretty straightforward, just test it with a couple dictionnaries and values and see if it does what you want.